# How to know ip address of nodes under ELB in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, ip-address, vpn, amazon-elb

I am running my application in VPN having a public ELB over 4 nodes, I want to know the ipAddress of all nodes behind that ELB.

Comment: Why do you need to know the IP addresses?

Comment: I agree with @MarkB , why do you need to know the instance's ip addresses? If you want to connect to instances in a private subnet from your VPN you'll need to add route propagation in private subnet's route table. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_VPN.html#vpn-configure-routing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Can Create a **CLI Script**.

Using the **AWS CLI** -

Pass the ELB name to describe the LoadBalancer.

```
aws elb describe-load-balancers --load-balancer-name sarat-load-balancer
```

It returns a set of instance id running behind the load balancer in Json Format.
Extract the Instance ids and Put them in a **Loop**.

Pass the Instance ids to describe the Instance.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-xxxxxxxxxx
```

It returns a set of data with public ips of the instances in Json Format.

You can do the same with **SDK**.

Hope It Helps.. :)